# What's the exact maximum value of `long long int` in C++?

Tags: c++, long-integer

I've been using `c++` for over 3 months and I can't figure out the exact maximum value of numbers in `long long int`.

Does anyone know the value?

Comment: You can check `std::numeric_limits<long long int>::max`

Comment: The macro [`LLONG_MAX`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/) also contains the value.

Answer (score 7):

It depends on the system. The C++ standard only guarantees that the *minimum size* for `long long int` [will be 64-bits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types). This is also by far the most common size.

With a 64-bit size, the maximum number that can be represented will be `2^63 - 1`, which equals `9223372036854775807`. The reason for this exact size, is that we need half of the bit combinations for the negative numbers, then one for `0` and the rest for the positive numbers.

The max value on a specific system can also be checked programmatically with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<long long int>::max();
}
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> 9223372036854775807
> ```

Answer (score 3):

`long long int` doesn't have a fixed maximum value specified by C++ language - it depends on the platform.

Use `std::numeric_limits<long long>::max()` (from [`<limits>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) header) to get its maximum value.

Comment: The output for `signed` and `unsigned` are different though and OP asked for signed.

Comment: @nada: That's likely but not formally necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The guarantee by the C++ Standard for the `long long` modifier is that it will have a width of at least 64 bits. (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types)).

The exact width of the type is, however, dependant on the particular platform, so you might get more thatn 64 bits for your types.

To check the maximum and minimum number a `long long int`type can hold on your machine and implementation, use the `<limits>` library with `std::numeric_limits<long long>`. You can read more about that [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits).